# How to plot a rectangle behind a function over time

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

I'm plotting a timeseries in pandas using matplotlib and I'm trying to color a plot look like this.

[image: Illustration on the wanted result]

I have the times for the A-F points. I've tried to get the position of them in the plot using

```
gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', debug_print_onclick_event)
```

and ended up with x positions being around 22'395'850 (not even close to unixtime :S)

My code basically looks like this:

```
plot = data.plot(legend=False) #where data is the timeseries (pandas.DataFrame).
plot.add_patch(
    plt.Rectangle(
        (0,22395760), 
        60, 
        45,
        facecolor='green',
        edgecolor='green'
    )
)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

But nothings of the patch shows up.
Also tested to use time directly, it actually ran but no patch was rendered.

```
plt.Rectangle(
    (0,datetime_D), 
    60, 
    4*pandas.datetools.Minutes(15),
    facecolor='green',
    edgecolor='green'
)
```

What is the underlying type? How should I position `things` in time in matplotlib? Any uglyhack working is appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have swapped x and y as first argument of Rectangle((x,y), ...). Rectangle((22395760, 0), ...)

Comment: omg, it might be the solution, I'm testing it right now, hold on.

Comment: btw plot.axvspan() seems a better match for what you want to do

Comment: Thanks a lot @lodagro. Initially I had some problems with the width of the rectangle, either it was in minutes or in days depending on which method I used for the plotting.
But axvspan worked like a charm.
`pl.gca().axvspan(date,date+2*pandas.datetools.Minute(15),facecolor='green',edgecolor='green',alpha=0.3)`
Make a summery of your 2 comments as an answer and I will pick it as the solution.

Comment: made it a bit of a combination of all comments. probably cleaner to remove comments here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have swapped x and y as first argument of `Rectangle((x,y), ...)`.
`Rectangle((22395760, 0), ...)`

Instead of using a patch, `plot.axvspan()` seems a better match for what you want to do.

```
plt.gca().axvspan(date,date+2*pandas.datetools.Minute(15),facecolor='green',edge‌ color='green',alpha=0.3)
```